# Can I add my remaining Schengen days to my new 90 days?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules, day-counting

I left the Schengen in June after staying 88 days. My 90 days outside the Schengen finishes next month. My question is, the 2 days I have left from the last 180 day period - can I add these together with my new 90 days? Can I go I fx. my embassy after two days and have my passport stamped again while in the Schengen?

Hope the question is clear enough and that someone has a word of advice abou this.

Thank you!

Comment: BTW usually people stay in Schengen area a lot less then 90 day. If you do continuously nearly 90 days (after 90 day break), it may seems you are working in EU. Never do it, and never use visa for other purpose then the visa type allow you. With actual "climate" and exchange of information, you risk to have consequence for the rest of your live.

Comment: There is no last 180 day period.

Comment: If this were possible, a 30-year-old entering the Schengen area for the first time would be able to stay in the Schengen area for up to 15 years by rolling forward all the unused days from the first 30 years of his or her life.  Even if it were limited to the single 180-day period before the current entry, it would allow everyone entering for the first time, or more than 180 days after they last left, to stay for 180 days.

Answer (score 4):

No, Schengen days do NOT carry over. Under very few circumstance can you stay more than 90 days in any 180 day period with a short-stay visa.

[Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Ajl0028) says:

> In certain cases, the period of validity of a visa may be extended

They do not go into further detail than this, but adding days "because you didn't use them" will most definitely not work.