# Stay in the Schengen area for two consecutive 180-day periods

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Can I use a balance remaining from my first 180-day period and add 90 days from my second 180-day period, without leaving the Schengen area?

Comment: There is no ‘first’ or ‘second’ period, the 180 days is a rolling timeline. See https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en to understand how many days you may stay, and this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143957/can-i-add-my-remaining-schengen-days-to-my-new-90-days

Comment: No, you cannot. Staying longer that 90 days needs a D-Visa. The main reason for the introduction of 90/180 days rule was to prevent the misuse of short-term visits.

Comment: Are you from Brazil?  Brazil and maybe a couple of other countries still use the old method of counting, with discrete 180-day periods, because of a treaty or something like that.  With that method of counting, where you can trigger your 180-day period with a single day in the zone, go away for 90 days, and then return for 179 days.

Answer (score 4):

### It's a sliding window, not a period

You may be thinking the 180 days are Jan. 1-July 1, or 6-month anniversaries or something.   Not at all.

The 180 days in question are starting from 180 days ago. So August 20 through today (Feb 15).  Tomorrow, the 180 days will be August 21 til tomorrow (Feb 16).

If 90 of those 180 days have been in Schengen, then you cannot enter Schengen today.  If 60 of those 180 days were in Schengen, then you can spend 30 more days in Schengen *as of today*, and this gets to be re-evaluated day by day as past Schengen days may scroll off.

So for insatnce if you spent 88 days in Schengen, then spent 100 days outside of Schengen, then 80 of your last 180 days were in Schengen.  But you can still stay for 90 days, because for the next 80 days, an in-Schengen days will slide out of the window as fast as new in-Schengen days accrue.   So your day-count will remain at 80 until near the end, when the old in-Schengen days have entirely slid out of frame, and then only the new ones will count.

Comment: There are different rules for Brazilians.  The asker's surname seems Portuguese.  It's a distinct possibility.

Comment: @phoog OP would need to say that.  Trying to guess at it from an interpretation of such thin data, well, that would be bad.  *You didn't just DV for that, did you?*